# How to make screenshots not save into hard disk

Tags: 22.04

In previous version of ubuntu(20) ctrl+shift+printscreen would allow you to save part of screen into the clipboard and not into your screeshots folder. Is there any way to replicate this behaviour on ubuntu 22.04?
Pressing the prt scrn button does allow me to take partial screenshot however it does save the image into my screenshots folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do NOT want screenshots to be saved to file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420360/i-do-not-want-screenshots-to-be-saved-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, doing any print screen action saves the screenshot *both* as a file under "Pictures/Screenshots" and in the clipboard. Thus, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the screenshot you just made onto a document, or, if you changed your mind, retrieve the file.

To revert to the old behavior, you could install the previous `gnome-screenshot` tool, disable the current shortcut keys under "Settings" - "Keyboard", Screenshots section, and define custom shortcut keys that replicate the old behavior.